# can we use our own service for push notifications instaed of WNS cloud?

Tags: windows-8

I'm developing a application where my client application need to receive regular notifications for particular events. I find that to implement pushnotifications we have to do it through cloud..
Is it possible to implement push notifications by our local service

thanks and regards,
harsha

Answer (score 1):

Per the workflow pictured below, the "Cloud Service" merely needs to be accessible from your application as it's deployed on client machines. It does, however, need to have a secure connection to WNS, but you can host the "Cloud Service" on premises if you like, as long as it's available on the public internet for the Windows 8 clients to access. You cannot, however, host the service on the client device itself.

Of course, if you use your host the service on premises, you'll need to handle the infrastructure, scaling, security, of the "Cloud Service" yourself.

**EDIT:** Note that WNS is a constant in this, and is hosted by Microsoft "in the cloud", so as Jerry mentioned in his response, that's not something you can move to a local or on-premises service.

If they are 'regular' notifications, you could perhaps investigate [periodic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/08/09/windows-8-notifications-periodic-notifications.aspx) or [scheduled notifications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/08/08/windows-8-notifications-scheduled-notifications.aspx) as well.

[image: Push notification workflow]

Comment: Thanks Jim... But in order to avail WNS services for push notification I need to place my app in market store... is it mandatory to place my application in store if I avail WNS services?

Comment: You definitely need a store account and an app registered to get the Package SID and secret; however, the app can run and use notifications without being actually in the store. I'm not certain if that's in compliance with the terms of service though, so definitely check that resource. I do it all the time for demos/testing.

Comment: Thanks Jim.. so can't we implement push mechanism without using WNS?

Comment: nope - you might be able to rig something up that does polling or some sort of socket communication, but that's a lot of infrastructure to recreate (if indeed you can even get the level of control you'd need for a generic solution).

Comment: @JimO'Neil For Local updates Notification.(i.e: current details of the running app.) can be done without use of WNS. Is that Right?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. There is no mechanism to "push" to a Windows 8 device that is not also using WNS to route that message. Your service can do a lot, but must leverage WNS. This has to do with security, reliability, and (honestly) it is what it is. WNS is a requirement.

I get why you might ask this question.

I hope this answers it for you.